# Convert date input from HTML to MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, node.js, date, input

I'm working with node.js (for an Electron app) and I wanted to know how to convert a date that comes from an HTML input (dd/mm/yyyy), into a correct DATE type for MySQL DB (yyyy-mm-dd) ?

I checked the Moment.js but I don't know how to use it here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In moment.js

var moment = require('moment');

var date = moment('12/04/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY');

var train_date = date.format('YYYYMMDD');

console.log(train_date);